# setInterval equivalent in Android/Java?

Tags: android, service

I want to be able to run a service that checks with a remote server at predefined intervals. How would I go about doing such a thing in Android? Example: The user sets an option that they want to check for updates every 10 minutes, how would I do this?

Comment: apparently the best way to do this delayed checks every 10 minutes or so is to use Alarm Manager, haven't used it myself but will implement it soon. The accepted answer works well but will drain the client battery quicker. I don't say that will happen, it is just what I have read on different posts all over

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can use the handler for that, like

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

private Runnable updateData = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
         //call the service here
         ////// set the interval time here
         handler.postDelayed(updateData,10000);
    }
}
```

you can set the user define time in postDelayed() method

here are the link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

https://web.archive.org/web/20200810154212/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/using-handler-in-android.html

http://www.satyakomatineni.com/akc/display?url=DisplayNoteIMPURL&reportId=3496

http://www.helloandroid.com/taxonomy/term/43

Comment: I am getting `the local variable updateData may not have been initialized` (first it made me declare it final. Any ideas?

Comment: @snapfractalpop It needs to be declared as a method not a local variable

Comment: @MatthewMcveigh not necessarily, as long as it is declared globally then it should be fine. http://i.imgur.com/bm9vEx3.png

Comment: Android IDE, Java 8: Illegal self reference